# Other way to access helper class in Java

Tags: java, android, class

I transfered some of my most used methods in an external `HelperClass`:

```
package com.example;

public final class HelperClass {

   public static int dp_to_px(int dp) {

        final float scale = MainActivity.getAppContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);

    }

}
```

Currently I'm accessing them this way:

```
package com.example2;

import com.example.HelperClass;

    ...

    int px = HelperClass.dp_to_px(10);
    relativeLayout.setPadding(px, px, px, px);

    ...
```

I'm fine with it, but is there any way to write

```
import com.example.HelperClass.dp_to_px;

    int dp = dp_to_px(10);
```

This way you would only have to import the needed methods and not the whole `HelperClass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static import is what you want

`import static com.example.HelperClass.dp_to_px`

---

Ref:

> The static import construct allows unqualified access to static
> members without inheriting from the type containing the static
> members. Instead, the program imports the members, either
> individually:
>
> import static java.lang.Math.PI;
>
> or en masse:
>
> import static java.lang.Math.*;
>
> Once the static members have been imported, they may
> be used without qualification:
>
> double r = cos(PI * theta);
>
> The static
> import declaration is analogous to the normal import declaration.
> Where the normal import declaration imports classes from packages,
> allowing them to be used without package qualification, the static
> import declaration imports static members from classes, allowing them
> to be used without class qualification.
>
> So when should you use static
> import? Very sparingly! Only use it when you'd otherwise be tempted to
> declare local copies of constants, or to abuse inheritance (the
> Constant Interface Antipattern). In other words, use it when you
> require frequent access to static members from one or two classes. If
> you overuse the static import feature, it can make your program
> unreadable and unmaintainable, polluting its namespace with all the
> static members you import. Readers of your code (including you, a few
> months after you wrote it) will not know which class a static member
> comes from. Importing all of the static members from a class can be
> particularly harmful to readability; if you need only one or two
> members, import them individually. Used appropriately, static import
> can make your program more readable, by removing the boilerplate of
> repetition of class names

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html